# FlatList contentContainerStyle -> justifyContent: 'center' causes issues with scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile-development

I have a `FlatList` component where I render x number of `TouchableHighlight`. I need all components in the `FlatList` aligned vertically to center.

The problem is that if I put `justifyContent: center` in `contentContainerStyle` nothing happens but, if I add `flex: 1` to `contentContainerStyle` I get the result I want. It is cool if I doesn't have to make scroll, but when I have a number of components in the `FlatList` that forces do scroll to see all of it the scroll start in the center of these list and don't let me scroll.

These is my code:

```
<FlatList
        style = {{flex: 0.7, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
        data = {this.props.actions}
        contentContainerStyle = {{justifyContent:'center',}}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        renderItem = {({item, index})=>{
          return (
            <TouchableHighlight
              style = {{alignItems: 'center', margin: 8, paddingTop: 8, paddingBottom: 8, //flex: 1,
              borderColor: ConstantesString.colorGrisFlojito, backgroundColor: '#d7deeb',
              borderRadius: 10,
            }}
              underlayColor = {ConstantesString.colorAzulTouched}
              onPress = {()=>{
                item.action();
              }}>
              <Text
                style = {{color: '#005288' , textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20}}
              >
                {item.name}
              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          )
        }}
      />
```

I don't know if this is a bug or I am just doing bad.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

*Its not a bug and you're not doing bad*, it is the expected behaviour since you're adding explicit `flex` to the **container** of the `ScrollView's` list making it take the overall `height` of the screen, hence *Scrollable only to the screen's content*.

You need to use `flexGrow` instead of `flex` to solve it

> The flex grow factor of a flex item is *relative to the size* of the **other children** in the **flex-container**

```
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}
    //... other props
/>
```